# How to feed a function one value at a time from a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, split, list-comprehension, chunks

I have a function `modify` as follows:

```py
list_with_chunks = [['hi','hello','how are you?'],['i','am','fine'],['what','about you?','.']]
flatten_list = ['hi','hello',...]
empty_list = []

# building the function to convert our sentences in list_with_chunks into another form:
def modify(sentence):
    # do stuff here

  # returning the result and appending them in empty_list
  return empty_list.append(sentence*2)
```

I call the function as below:

```py
for i in flatten_list:
    modify(i)
```

But, I want to send each sentence directly from `list_with_chunks` instead of flattening it and append the result in `empty_list`. How do I do that?

TIA.

Comment: Any help here? @Barmar . Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear, but perhaps try something like `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(map,itertools.repeat(modify),list_with_chunks)))`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Let me try again. I simply want to send each sentence directly from `list_with_chunks` into the function `modify(sentence,top_n=5)` instead from `flatten_list`. 

I tried your solution, and I got this result:

`[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]`

Comment: That is because you function returns `None` no matter what its input. You'd have to change that and not append within the function (which I'd argue is poor design, anyway) but let it return its result instead. Also, it is not clear to me what you mean by sentence, Is a sentence a sublist or a single character? The snippet I've posted assumes the latter.

Comment: Here is a simple example input `list_with_chunks = [list(c) for c in "list of lists".split()]` `modify = str.upper` . you can test the snippet with that.

Comment: By sentence I mean something like this: `[['hi','hello','how are you?'],['i','am',fine..how about you?']]`

Comment: If you mean something like this it would help to put something like this in your example instead of letting every one guess what you mean.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Sorry for the confusion. I've edited the original question.

Comment: Thank you. You should also provide a working function `modify`. It needn't do anything clever, just take an input and return an output, so one can see what type of input/output to expect.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thank you for the inputs. I've modified accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question entirely! But is this what you looking for:

```
for x in list_with_chunks:
    for y in x:
        modify(y)
```

You just need to iterate every element inside list again in order to add them in the empty list.

Answer (score -1):

Use a nested loop through list_with_chunks.

```
for i in range(len(list_with_chunks)):
    for j in range(len(list_with_chunks[i])):
        modify(list_with_chunks[i][j], top_n=5)
```

Comment: This gives me a TypeError.

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-f2fb08579ef7> in <module>()
----> 1 for i in len(list_with_chunks):
      2     for j in len(list_with_chunks[i]):
      3         modify(list_with_chunks[i][j], top_n=5)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Please remember `list_with_chunks` contains `strings` as its values.

Comment: No, it isn't. It is list of lists: `[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]` like this.

Comment: Could you show your code from list_with_chunks initiation to that error.

Comment: ```list_with_chunks = [['hi','hello','how are you?'],['i','am','fine'],['what','about you?','.']]
new_list = []

def modify(sentence):
  return new_list.append(sentence*2)

for i in len(list_with_chunks):
    for j in len(list_with_chunks[i]):
        modify(list_with_chunks[i][j])
```